# Bootstrapping for statistic computed from statistic

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

Let's say we want to compute a statistic from another statistic. In the example, we have mRNA levels for patients per gene. First we compute the median level for each gene. Then we compute skewness across all genes. If we want to bootstrap this estimate (skewness of the median), should we:

1. Resample from the original dataset: Resample the *patients* (e.g. the original data), and repeat the process of computing the median and then skewness $R$ times.
2. Resample from the computed medians: Compute the median level for each gene. Then resample from the *medians* and compute the skewness

I think that 1. seems more correct intuitively, but I don't have good justification for why 2. is not correct. Method 2 seems like the only way that this would be possible if you were only given the median mRNA level and not the original level per patient.

Using the example below, we come to two very different conclusions regarding the skewness: Using method 1. there is a positive skew and method 2 the interval overlaps zero so it is unclear if there is a positive skew.

```r
# Load the sample data
kao.subset <- structure(list(BRC029 = c(4.74305, 5.10707, 5.94761, 3.44068,
9.33847, 10.87651, 8.28156, 5.44167, 5.87587, 10.36539, 8.27666,
4.97341, 3.76643, 9.24611, 4.23723, 3.92152, 7.48572, 5.623,
4.93197, 5.41712, 4.71745, 5.46986, 6.15549, 9.50374, 7.59796,
8.99629, 5.79387, 11.10206, 3.70463, 3.87049), BRC169 = c(4.94514,
5.00712, 6.91025, 3.61399, 8.98971, 10.82085, 9.04781, 4.64574,
5.61403, 10.29571, 8.81521, 5.19936, 3.9543, 9.1926, 4.52041,
3.90106, 7.61311, 5.60605, 4.90028, 5.47134, 4.48253, 5.11513,
7.24642, 10.47119, 7.82537, 9.34573, 6.43661, 11.1847, 3.85258,
3.88296), BRC126 = c(4.93395, 4.86377, 5.44667, 3.66928, 8.95412,
9.9988, 8.21216, 5.99033, 6.86534, 10.48625, 8.55281, 4.93735,
4.4387, 9.27186, 4.42022, 4.05452, 8.56225, 5.31267, 5.91671,
5.2817, 4.35755, 5.3159, 7.41668, 8.76194, 7.5821, 8.36142, 6.88035,
11.0292, 3.96878, 3.97981), BRC284 = c(4.65166, 4.80212, 4.98935,
3.63855, 9.36701, 10.04496, 8.27855, 5.00277, 5.99518, 10.16504,
8.59976, 4.94729, 3.8562, 10.04782, 4.18717, 4.75076, 7.81885,
5.33957, 5.82161, 6.58109, 4.26822, 5.14157, 6.84608, 8.31128,
8.34354, 9.14487, 7.80606, 10.78417, 3.98914, 3.86691), BRC260 = c(4.71929,
4.62831, 7.01562, 3.6122, 10.73436, 10.00529, 8.58129, 4.59339,
5.78545, 10.38359, 7.72686, 5.09261, 4.36992, 11.00277, 4.71242,
3.82653, 8.34209, 6.10741, 4.77252, 6.03383, 4.55166, 5.72442,
6.74364, 8.66947, 10.14184, 9.34311, 5.65845, 11.25569, 3.59389,
4.01226), BRC302 = c(5.25276, 4.70241, 6.58105, 3.71339, 9.72645,
10.86296, 8.17234, 4.59338, 5.94282, 10.24542, 9.26434, 5.55616,
3.75259, 9.54288, 4.61423, 4.39076, 8.31407, 5.42641, 5.53277,
5.13778, 4.58879, 5.80936, 6.82155, 10.71993, 7.79165, 9.04711,
5.77136, 11.18276, 3.71704, 3.99568), BRC010 = c(4.50055, 4.69466,
5.57878, 3.54275, 9.55131, 10.83882, 8.56418, 5.55026, 8.20371,
10.11936, 10.63773, 4.83077, 3.7462, 9.86333, 4.65242, 3.99778,
8.18935, 5.95772, 4.86349, 4.99515, 4.36393, 5.0985, 7.88089,
9.75057, 8.40021, 8.74, 6.90391, 11.18691, 3.7133, 3.83501),
    BRC050 = c(4.95011, 4.8458, 5.93241, 3.53809, 8.18229, 11.66313,
    8.79616, 4.39311, 6.36607, 10.42696, 8.90852, 5.12007, 3.49751,
    10.71076, 4.77217, 4.16255, 8.71009, 5.82151, 6.10564, 7.19803,
    4.51864, 5.91271, 7.09309, 9.2807, 8.6844, 9.22579, 10.23187,
    10.88453, 3.80715, 3.8508), BRC049 = c(4.88015, 4.89262,
    6.20679, 3.58428, 8.96602, 9.98657, 8.80939, 5.51403, 5.79119,
    9.96514, 10.32234, 5.31669, 3.67993, 10.5198, 4.54416, 4.07932,
    7.38482, 5.87599, 4.79184, 5.45732, 4.26972, 5.39987, 7.89986,
    8.78119, 8.00929, 8.43456, 7.37217, 11.48254, 4.3173, 3.76027
    ), BRC022 = c(5.28222, 4.99896, 6.55623, 3.57728, 7.27467,
    10.69026, 8.38087, 5.45693, 5.61988, 10.15349, 8.85353, 5.43278,
    3.57608, 9.1086, 4.67742, 4.47203, 7.48628, 5.83997, 5.56645,
    5.53354, 4.70751, 5.07577, 6.68344, 7.93255, 8.13909, 8.60922,
    6.85545, 11.01972, 3.8588, 4.18664), BRC139 = c(5.00289,
    4.77237, 5.09123, 3.97979, 8.4186, 10.45709, 9.21833, 5.62102,
    5.63092, 10.745, 8.03025, 4.93881, 3.48431, 10.67221, 5.09169,
    4.17878, 7.44926, 6.0642, 11.00412, 5.29872, 4.48566, 5.7207,
    6.6903, 8.53067, 7.60154, 9.45619, 6.03923, 10.44999, 3.78058,
    4.06383), BRC143 = c(4.64479, 5.23903, 4.29467, 3.55888,
    8.75103, 11.40496, 8.80356, 4.39765, 7.67453, 10.2523, 9.33943,
    4.757, 3.47612, 9.73509, 4.72404, 3.87101, 7.99514, 5.7545,
    6.31709, 5.08507, 4.34596, 4.67076, 7.35649, 8.71579, 7.73998,
    8.99791, 6.76832, 10.9742, 3.85628, 3.98635), BRC323 = c(4.84614,
    4.43173, 6.18441, 3.39853, 10.16416, 10.26073, 8.66155, 4.27192,
    9.29591, 10.66457, 8.49685, 5.28627, 3.62795, 10.7949, 4.20556,
    3.87291, 8.71983, 5.08027, 6.35894, 5.94493, 4.07019, 5.01582,
    7.46485, 8.6135, 10.33834, 9.57571, 5.72316, 11.43949, 3.79655,
    3.88109), BRC081 = c(4.74634, 4.71474, 6.4888, 3.45221, 9.1591,
    10.91018, 9.17417, 4.38095, 8.13254, 10.33187, 8.17721, 5.06002,
    3.7788, 9.74116, 4.64019, 3.96899, 8.02011, 6.01228, 4.92899,
    5.20193, 4.79059, 5.17979, 7.26985, 8.46194, 8.0632, 9.22739,
    5.93553, 11.16311, 3.92086, 3.96238), BRC192 = c(5.02898,
    4.47488, 5.3343, 3.83016, 8.9073, 10.69749, 8.92578, 4.59455,
    6.88969, 10.50445, 9.13237, 5.02605, 3.65221, 10.86518, 4.67533,
    4.03766, 8.26209, 5.70225, 6.25779, 5.03817, 4.19161, 5.30116,
    7.18646, 8.88873, 8.09827, 9.36218, 6.1373, 11.22717, 3.90678,
    3.88426), BRC067 = c(4.76682, 5.1189, 4.11647, 3.92188, 8.27421,
    11.99442, 8.84792, 4.70873, 6.60983, 9.88186, 6.50437, 5.24258,
    3.5459, 9.68106, 4.68678, 4.18656, 7.25614, 6.2202, 7.15256,
    5.80595, 4.61666, 5.37261, 5.87245, 6.87948, 7.33665, 9.43935,
    6.53073, 10.91787, 3.83818, 4.02639), BRC062 = c(4.89404,
    4.75178, 5.08603, 3.52149, 7.92291, 10.94474, 9.45138, 4.84404,
    6.24905, 10.59065, 6.56951, 5.20195, 3.96018, 11.10839, 4.6385,
    6.55345, 7.63654, 5.80819, 12.72623, 7.30059, 4.35791, 5.36946,
    5.42674, 8.36018, 8.05562, 9.2776, 6.34084, 11.93217, 3.57289,
    3.83208), BRC171 = c(4.51732, 5.05196, 5.17317, 3.56582,
    8.92442, 10.7863, 9.11642, 4.89645, 6.69173, 10.6181, 7.80963,
    5.08416, 3.76989, 9.91519, 4.22422, 3.90936, 7.97142, 5.24461,
    8.12026, 5.64111, 4.21866, 5.09375, 6.46671, 9.20674, 8.58744,
    9.67422, 5.40933, 11.31149, 3.79448, 3.77504), BRC154 = c(4.55201,
    5.02529, 5.65252, 3.46415, 8.8636, 11.34893, 9.02232, 4.78659,
    8.00197, 9.54766, 8.6674, 4.91227, 4.05127, 9.87895, 4.51248,
    4.052, 7.97784, 5.85317, 5.828, 5.67831, 4.50668, 5.04108,
    7.13026, 8.50994, 7.99592, 9.6469, 5.96262, 11.01838, 4.1336,
    3.80101), BRC172 = c(4.56564, 4.64006, 5.51115, 3.63541,
    9.85177, 10.61676, 8.55384, 4.8707, 6.69927, 10.2345, 8.6918,
    4.95377, 3.88703, 9.59292, 4.45392, 3.95934, 8.4552, 5.7009,
    5.89305, 4.66269, 4.72573, 5.52067, 7.2423, 9.35224, 7.93715,
    8.89167, 7.05688, 10.51077, 4.04673, 3.91905), BRC288 = c(4.83889,
    4.59141, 4.96039, 3.61543, 8.80103, 10.72165, 8.64168, 4.93207,
    6.61586, 10.2515, 9.62962, 5.19785, 3.65992, 9.11176, 4.65673,
    3.9306, 7.94603, 5.47903, 5.33873, 5.30166, 4.42861, 5.46302,
    7.22745, 9.45053, 7.7448, 8.47164, 6.3294, 11.63401, 3.86574,
    3.96475), BRC101 = c(4.67512, 4.44536, 5.80453, 3.59866,
    9.35431, 9.7605, 8.77394, 4.34798, 7.89294, 10.04821, 9.22835,
    5.22846, 4.21452, 10.98298, 4.45162, 3.83516, 7.78125, 5.72725,
    5.09319, 4.93284, 4.45945, 5.25827, 7.42069, 8.55725, 8.88968,
    8.04732, 7.22444, 10.85023, 3.82591, 3.81103), BRC317 = c(4.84245,
    4.48358, 4.68389, 3.44646, 8.71011, 10.66552, 9.04644, 5.46549,
    7.48603, 10.21942, 8.17142, 5.03354, 3.39412, 8.98476, 4.64492,
    4.0073, 7.99149, 5.89012, 5.9701, 5.03498, 4.58705, 5.31091,
    7.25011, 8.97145, 7.97199, 8.77591, 7.50551, 10.76689, 3.65571,
    3.96902), BRC157 = c(4.88088, 4.55947, 5.65628, 3.60734,
    9.07123, 10.41685, 8.6387, 4.17742, 5.34128, 10.43342, 7.71615,
    5.11993, 3.93477, 11.01601, 4.65078, 3.942, 8.67892, 5.81442,
    5.40771, 5.32423, 4.44033, 5.00892, 7.93214, 9.10614, 8.1918,
    9.88927, 7.02239, 11.12344, 3.67863, 3.8022), BRC122 = c(4.37255,
    5.265, 5.66925, 3.48378, 9.44307, 11.42496, 8.27511, 4.41975,
    7.39383, 9.95217, 9.15261, 4.82107, 4.10036, 10.22617, 4.42197,
    3.97861, 8.00251, 5.42073, 5.17909, 6.27879, 4.42726, 4.77188,
    7.38165, 8.97516, 7.824, 9.48758, 6.53685, 10.89124, 3.65753,
    3.69469)), row.names = c("85289_at", "5224_at", "79733_at",
"101928847_at", "23531_at", "5573_at", "6595_at", "8556_at",
"2770_at", "126328_at", "10123_at", "101929718_at", "9824_at",
"1942_at", "116931_at", "57575_at", "100996412_at", "9407_at",
"185_at", "115948_at", "101929717_at", "100506606_at", "9258_at",
"5698_at", "92105_at", "22796_at", "388610_at", "27249_at", "340578_at",
"389043_at"), class = "data.frame")

library(boot)
library(moments)

# Method 1: Compute median across genes in the resample step from original data
gene.median.skew <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,]

  gm <- apply(d, 2, median)
  skewness(gm)
}
results <- boot(data=t(kao.subset), statistic=gene.median.skew, R=1000)
boot.ci(results, type = c("norm","basic","perc", "bca"))
#> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
#> Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
#> 
#> CALL : 
#> boot.ci(boot.out = results, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", 
#>     "bca"))
#> 
#> Intervals : 
#> Level      Normal              Basic         
#> 95%   ( 0.3664,  0.4697 )   ( 0.3637,  0.4680 )  
#> 
#> Level     Percentile            BCa          
#> 95%   ( 0.3887,  0.4930 )   ( 0.3628,  0.4710 )  
#> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
#> Some BCa intervals may be unstable

# Method 2: First compute the median across each gene
#           Then resample from the medians
gene.median <- apply(kao.subset, 1, median)
gene.skew <- function(data, indices) {
  skewness(data[indices])
}
results2 <- boot(data=gene.median, statistic = gene.skew, R=1000)
boot.ci(results2, type = c("norm","basic","perc", "bca"))
#> BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
#> Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates
#> 
#> CALL : 
#> boot.ci(boot.out = results2, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc", 
#>     "bca"))
#> 
#> Intervals : 
#> Level      Normal              Basic         
#> 95%   (-0.2032,  1.0513 )   (-0.2909,  1.0185 )  
#> 
#> Level     Percentile            BCa          
#> 95%   (-0.1619,  1.1475 )   (-0.1426,  1.1648 )  
#> Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm having a hard time following the code, but might you in one case be estimating the median of the skewness, while in the other you are estimating the skewness of the medians?

Comment: In the first case, the median is computed $R$ times and the skewness is computed on each $R$. In the second case, the median is computed once, and then the skewness is computed on the $R$ resamples of the medians.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the skewness of the gene-median might be the same for each gene?